# Proxying Kibana

Tags: nginx, proxy, kibana

I'm having some(a lot of) difficulties, trying to setup a reverse proxy for Kibana.

The general idea is that we want to set up a reverse proxy so select customers have access to Kibana. E.g. when customer A goes to "kibana.company.com/ customera" he is automatically forwarded to Kibana and has access to logistics about their data. We have multiple customers we need to proxy, so eventually we will set up ldap or AD, to help us handle this.

So far i've tried both Apache2 and Nginx, but i've run into problems using both of them. I'm currently working on Apache, with a very simple configuration.

http://pastebin.com/1gt5KLyP

When i go to localhost/kibana/ i'm forwarded to localhost/app/kibana, but i get a URL not found message.

As far as NginX goes, i run into a problem where i forward to Kibana, but it get's indefinitely stuck in a loading loop. ("Kibana is loading blablabla... good stuff will be cached"), but i never actually shows the dashboard, no matter which configuration i tried, i could never get the dashboard to show. This is a sample config, but it's changed a lot during testing.

http://pastebin.com/PP4Fu1Cs

Am i going about it the right way or is their a simpler way to do what i'm trying to do.

EDIT: I'm now getting the same results with Apache after adding

ProxyPass /kibana/ http:// ip /app/kibana

ProxyPassReverse /kibana/ http:// ip /app/kibana

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a FIDDLER and see where it is stuck.

I did a Reverse Proxy using Apache with the following config successfully.

```
ProxyPreserveHost ON

ProxyPass /portal1     http://IP1/home

ProxyPassReverse /portal2   http://IP2/home
```

These are the modules I loaded

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: did you actually complete this task using kibana? Because i can proxy the site just fine, it's just that it ends up stuck in an infinite loading loop.

Comment: No. But i can try it and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the problem where Kibana is stuck forever on the loading screen, you can try the following:

1. Stop the Kibana service, on Ubuntu:

   `sudo service kibana stop`
2. Delete `optimize/bundles` directory:

   `sudo rm -rf /opt/kibana/optimize/bundles`
3. Start the Kibana service, on Ubuntu:

   `sudo service kibana start`
4. Wait for a minute or so before reloading the browser (you can keep an eye on the log at `/var/log/kibana.log` to see when the server is ready again).

Answer (score 0):

I think your proxy is blocking some of kibana's requests. Check in your browser inspector all requests and responses there shouldn't be any errors.

There is a simple configuration in nginx:

```
location ~ (|/app/kibana|/bundles/|/status|/plugins|/elasticsearch/|)  {
    proxy_pass http://kibana:5601;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    rewrite /(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
```

If you want to show just charts without any additional buttons and panels, just add `?embed=true` parameter to your url e.g.

```
http://kibana/app/kibana#/visualize/edit/chart?embed=true&_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),...
```